# How can I use upper and lowercase for string in java?

Tags: java, string

I am currently working on a string ascending programme. It will be able to output a message that will indicate if the string input is in ascending order or not. The code works in the sense that it can detect if abc is ascending or bca is not.

The problem I have is getting the programme to detect strings that are in ascending order but use a mixture of lowercase and uppercase letters.

E.g.
abcdefgX

I thought setting my variable "word" as word = word.toString() but it doesn't make a difference - it can detect string either all in capital or all lowercase.

Here is my code.

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.print( "#Enter String" );
        String word = BIO.getString();
        Boolean inOrder = true;
        while (word.equals("END")) {
            if (word.equals("END")) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        while (inOrder) {
            word = word.toString();
            char previous = word.charAt(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < word.length() && inOrder; j++) {
                inOrder = word.charAt(j) >= previous;
                previous = word.charAt(j);
            }

            if (inOrder) {
                System.out.print(word + " letters in ascending order" + "\n");
            }else if (!inOrder) {
                System.out.print(word + "  letters not in ascending order" + "\n");
            }


            System.out.print( "#Enter String" );
            word = BIO.getString();
            inOrder = true;
            while (word.equals("END")) {
                if (word.equals("END")) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `if (word.equals("END"))` supposed to be doing _inside_ `while (word.equals("END"))` ?

Comment: It was the only way I knew how to get it so that once "END" is input the programme terminates.

Comment: converting to lowercase resolves any mixed case issues

Comment: If I convert to lowercase it will say I have input abcdefgX but the output will be abcdefgx which is wrong - I need it to be output abcdefgX is in ascending order.

Comment: you convert so you can compare. you can always keep a copy of the original if you want to display it

Comment: converting to lowercase didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--) to convert the `String s` to lower case before iterating over it.

**Edit:**

Change this

```
while (inOrder) {
  word = word.toString();
```

to this:

```
while (inOrder) {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: could you point out to me on the code where that needs to be please

Comment: This helped - the programme detected abcdefgX as being in ascending order but the only issue is that it will output "abcdefgx is in ascending order" I need it to output "abcdefgX in in ascending order"

Comment: Then you should remember the original `String` *before* converting to to lower case. Use this remembered `String` when you write the result.

Comment: To test my programme I am using a software called Charon. These are the inputs that it is testing:                                                             
abcdefgh
Xabcdefg
aXbcdefg
abXcdefg
abcXdefg
abcdXefg
abcdeXfg
abcdefXg
abcdefgX
ABCDEFGH
END

Comment: What is your last comment supposed to mean?

Comment: I did what you suggested and changed from word.toString() to word.toLowerCase() and it meant that the programme now detected "abcdefgX" as ascending - but the output message needs to have the original input in it too so it will say "abcdefgX is ascending" instead of abcdefgx - in lowercase.

Comment: then store a copy of the original @JoshGibson

Comment: Yes, and I've already told you how to do this. Do you expect me to do programming as a service for you? Do your work!

Comment: No - I don't expect a programming service - I was just stating that your answer partially solved my issue (y).

Comment: So again: "Then you should remember the original String before converting to to lower case. Use this remembered String when you write the result."